# Incorrect object "this" on context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm losing the context of the "This" object on the helper class on the following structure, and i can't figure out why.

Inside the *getAll* method, the *this* object is making reference to the object located on the *servicesDict* array on the main component.

I want that the *this* object refer the Entity1Utils class.

```
export class Entity1Utils {
    public getAll(context) {
        this.buildQueryParams();
        // this "this" refers to the object { id: 'entity1', method: this.entity1Utils.getAll }
        // located on servicesDict at ManagementComponent
    }

    private buildQueryParams() {
        // logical code
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-management',
    templateUrl: './management.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./management.component.css']
})

export class ManagementComponent implements OnInit {
    private entity1Utils: Entity1Utils;
    private servicesDict: any;

    constructor() {
        this.entity1Utils = new Entity1Utils();

        this.servicesDict = [
            { id: 'entity1', method: this.entity1Utils.getAll }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand which `this` you're talking about, where it is pointing to and where you want it to point at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), for example:

```js
method: this.entity1Utils.getAll.bind(this.entity1Utils)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the scope within the function (what `this` points to) is dictated by the object upon which the method is invoked.

```js
foo.doSomething() // inside doSomething, 'this' is foo
```

```js
const method = foo.doSomething;
method(); // 'this' is undefined
```

```js
const obj = { method: foo.doSomething }
obj.method() // 'this' is obj
```

---

You're passing a reference to the *method itself*, detached from the instance of your class:

```js
{ method: this.entity1Utils.getAll } // the getAll method itself
```

So when something downstream invokes it, it invokes it as a method on servicesDict:

```js
const service = serviceDict[0];

// 'getAll' invoked on the serviceDict entry, so inside
// the method 'this' points to the serviceDict entry
service.method()
```

You can fix this by making the method an arrow function, which binds it to the current scope:

```js
getAll = context => { ... }
```

Or by creating a new anonymous inline arrow function that preserves the scope:

```js
{ method: (...args) => this.entity1Utils.getAll(...args) }
```

Or by binding it explicitly:

```js
{ method: this.entity1Utils.getAll.bind(this.entity1Utils) }
```

Comment: Nice! I had faced this problem before, but none explanation was clean like yours. Now i got the how the context works. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickFreitas Which method did you use, Patrick, because the binding above would not bind to the `Entity1Utils` instance as requested, it would bind to the `ManagementComponent` instance. None of the suggested fixes here would do what you requested.

Comment: @MikeM I actually adapted the last approach mentioned above, and just figure out now that was exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I overlooked the `entity1Utils` bit. Updated the answer to account for it.

Comment: @PatrickFreitas I'd recommend doing the binding inside `Entity1Utils` so users of it don't have to deal with binding issues. Is there ever any reason it shouldn't be bound?

Comment: Inside the getAll method I'm updating the entity list and other variables located on the ManagementComponent, besides that i also use this this as context for dependency injection. So.. on the Management: this.servicesDict[0].method(this); and on the getAll method: <EntityService>context.injector.get(EntityService); and context.dataList += response.results;